# Disable send button in datagridview when mail sent

Tags: c#, email, datagridview

I'm working on a project and I need your help. I want to disable my Send button once I send the contents of datagridview to my email. Here is the code for sending the mail, and I want that the button becomes disabled once the mail has been sent.

```
private void dataGridNarocila_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {         
      string narocilo = "Narocilo.txt";
      using (StreamWriter pisi = File.CreateText(narocilo))
      {
         for (int i = 0; i > dataGridNarocila.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
            pisi.Write(dataGridNarocila.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "|" +
            dataGridNarocila.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "|" +
            dataGridNarocila.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "|" +
            dataGridNarocila.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "|" +
            dataGridNarocila.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "|" +
            dataGridNarocila.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            pisi.WriteLine(); 
         }
      }
   }

   catch { MessageBox.Show("Napaka pri naročanju"); }

   string mailBody = "\n";

   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridNarocila.Rows)
   {
      foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
      {
         mailBody += "" + cell.Value + " \n";
      }
   }
   var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
   client.EnableSsl = true;
   client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("urbanchy@gmail.com", "****");

   var mail = new MailMessage();
   mail.From = new MailAddress("youraccount@yahoo.com");
   mail.To.Add("urbanchy@gmail.com");
   mail.Subject = "This is the subject of the mail";
   mail.Body = mailBody;
   client.Send(mail);
   MessageBox.Show("Naročilo oddano");
   }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just set its `Enabled` property to `false`?

Comment: what he said... btn1.Enabled = False; (or whatever your button's name is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your button to false, like this:

```
btnNameHere.Enabled = false;
```

Or, to use your code specifically:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("urbancy@gmail.com", "***********");
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("youraccount@yahoo.com");
mail.To.Add("urbancy@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "This is the subject of the mail";
mail.Body = mailBody;
client.Send(mail);
MessageBox.Show("Order taken");
btnNameHere.Enabled = false;  // Add this line of code.
```

Just make sure that you re-enable it at some point - in case you need it again, as @alykins pointed out in the comments below.  To re-enable it, just do the opposite of what I showed above:

```
btnNameHere.Enabled = true;
```

Happy coding!

Comment: 1 thing to remember is that it might get re-enabled somewhere else... or it at least should as once you send an email, you will never be able to do so again lol. Make sure to re-enable it somewhere else. If you are trying to avoid multiple sends disable it as first thing, and upon successful sending, clear all the fields and re-enable the button (and error out on blank fields or something); ie validate before sending and do something before re-enabling the button to make it invalid that way you don't duplicate send.

Comment: @alykins - This is a very good point.  I will incorporate it into my answer.

Comment: The button is in datagridview, it is a cell. Like a column of buttons you know what I mean ? So I can't just choose it and set it's property to false.

Comment: Well i just aded this  dataGridNarocila.Columns[0].Visible = false; so its working thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `WPF`, set the `IsEnabled` property to `false`.

```
btn.IsEnabled = false;
```

For Windows application

```
btn.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

button1.Click -= button1_Click;

To disable the click event for button1

And use

button1.Click += button1_Click;

To enable it again.

Comment: how is that supposed to help anyone? Perhaps you could add some explanation of what the questioner was doing wrong, and explain why your code solution is the answer - that way, when someone else finds your answer it will be helpful and you will have **taught** something.

Comment: plus it doesn't even answer the question.